# Migrating a PHP 5.2 Website

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I'm currently working on a website for a client, but this website is running PHP version 5.2.17.

Can anyone recommend the best way to tackle this? I've experience in HTML/CSS/JS/JAVA with a basic understanding of PHP.

I'm thinking of rebuilding the website with a HTML5 framework and basically dumping this on top of the old PHP pages, integrating the MySQL database and passing through the links to not lose SEO, but ultimately do worry it may affect the site...

I've tried running a WAMP server but as it only goes as low as version 5.3 I get constant errors and the page displays without the CSS and has words overlapping etc.

Images attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your errors don't look like the result of different PHP versions.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I've tried deleting all the error causing PHP lines, but the site still displays without the CSS? this is in my test WAMP server, live it works fine.

Comment: Open your browser's console while loading this. The CSS files are likely 404, which is not the fault of PHP. More likely the fault of them just not being in the right place, or of Apache mod_rewrite mistakenly rewriting away from them.

Comment: From php version 5.2 to php version 5.3 it has very much changes. I recommend that you do  refactorice.

Comment: Hi Michael, your right it appears there are multiple 404 errors this website is very old (originally built in the 90's) and has been updated a few times, the last being 2011. So your suggesting the website isn't pointing to the correct CSS file? it appears to be pointing only to the jquery one...

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are encountering are to do with files which are being included not being found. Check through the code and identify the files that are being requested, then locate those files and correct the file paths, if the files can not be restored then remove the include statements entirely or comment them out, make sure they have been removed from evrrywhere.

Comment: I've removed all the broken PHP links, but the CSS is still broken, or at a minimum the site structure, the site has multiple CSS files but is only pointing to the Jquery one. When I change this to the Styles.css it still displays poorly but with some CSS elements.

Comment: If it the CSS files that are missing open up the source in your browser and try to browse to each stylesheet, if the browser reports not found then check if in the sites folder structure the stylesheet exists on the server in that location, if it doesnt then add the appropriate additional link tags for all the stylesheets, if they do then it means it is probably a misconfiguration in the url rewrite rules.